# Creating editor dynamically

Tags: eclipse, rcp, eclipse-plugin

I want to create an RCP application using view and editor extensions. 
I have created a view which has a tree view inside. When any object is clicked on this tree view, I want to open an editor on the right side. It will be something like the Eclipse Package Explorer - when you click any Java source file, it is opened in a new editor.

I can create an editor using plugin.xml file but how can i create editors dynamically when tree object is selected?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this tutorial? http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseEditors/article.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the editor open on a single click selection of an item in your tree, then you'll need to take a look at [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html) as well.

I feel that having a working knowledge of The Eclipse Selection Service will help you a great deal as you move forward developing your RCP application.